# InfluxDB query with tag where clause not returning results

Tags: influxdb

this looks like something really straightforward that I am messing up, but can't find what is wrong. I have a simple query where I am trying to retrieve measurements with a specific tag value. I am following the syntax of double quoting the tag_key and single quoting the tag value. E.g., `select "score","i_unique"::tag  from "events.flow"  where "i_unique" = 'my-value'`

If you see below:

```
> select "score","i_unique"::tag  from "events.flow"  limit 4
name: events.flow
time                score i_unique
----                ----- --------
1563464912039000000 462   "42422440-41124048-155896-42266768-229624-233640"
1563464912042000000 462   "42422440-41124048-155896-42266768-42352808-42270864"
......
> select "score","i_unique"::tag  from "events.flow"  where "i_unique" = '42422440-41124048-155896-42266768-229624-233640'
>
```

The tag value I want to query for, is in the time series as can be seen by the first select query. But, when I want to pick up just that value by adding a where clause, I am not getting any results.

Any help would be wonderful, Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an error on my insert. I was inserting an additional double quote for my tag. It is obvious now, when I look at the result of the search query, but missed it completely. So this was a problem with my insert and not select. Once I removed the additional `"`s, everything is making sense again.